# How can I create an animation method and put that in paint method? My code doesn't work

Tags: java, animation, methods, applet, awt

Why doesn't this work? I created a method for an animation loop of two pictures called animation(), 
and i want to put that in the paint method. How do i do this?

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Slot_Machine extends Applet
    {
    Image back;
    int coin=10;
    // Place instance variables here

    public void init ()
    {
        back= getImage(getDocumentBase(),"Images/Background/Slot Machine.png");
        // Place the body of the initialization method here
    } // init method

    public void animation(Graphics g)
    {
    Image Title1,Title2;
    Title1= getImage(getDocumentBase(),"Images/Title Animation/Title 1.png");
    Title2= getImage(getDocumentBase(),"Images/Title Animation/Title 2.png");
    while(true){
    g.drawImage(Title2,200,0,this);
    { try { Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000); } 
                catch ( Exception e ) { } }
    g.drawImage(Title1,200,0,this);
    { try { Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000); } 
                catch ( Exception e ) { } }
    }//end while(true) loop
    }//end animation

    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {   
        g.drawImage(back,0,0,this);
        animation(); //FROM THE METHOD ABOVE, WHY DOESNT THIS WORK? HOW DO I FIX THIS?
        String coins  = String.valueOf(coin);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.setFont(new Font("Impact",Font.PLAIN,30));
        g.drawString(coins,405,350);
        // Place the body of the drawing method here
    } // paint method
}
```

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See my answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Your `animation()` method has an infinite loop in it, which means that `paint()` never returns, which is causing the thread trying to start up the applet to hang while waiting for `paint()` to return.

If you want to run a forever-looping animation in the background, try doing it in another thread.  Take a look at [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).